# How does Python know where to find the module requested in an import statement?

Tags: python, file, module

Say I have a program that imports a module. I am free to use classes and methods within that module:

```
import re  # stored in C:\Python33\Lib\re
```

But, if I have another file in the same directory as the file that I am putting my code in, for example:

```
# testmodule.py
print('Success!')
```

I can import it in file that runs in the same directory:

```
import testmodule  # in the same directory as __file__
```

Outputs:

> Success!

And of course no error is returned when using `import re`.

What I want to know is, how does Python know where to look for a module specified in an `import` statement if the file location is not specifies yet different over several statements?

Comment: [The Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check it in `sys.path`. Python will start searching in the current directory, and then the other folders listed.

Answer (score 0):

from documentation, look at this: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path

http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

python has a defined modules search path.
please look in here[The Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)
is this what you meant?